# Unity3D - SphereCollider within another SphereCollider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

I´m working with Unity3D and have the following problem:

I want to have two Spheres, which react on MouseEvents, Raycast etc. via SphereCollider.
Now one Sphere is within the other. By clicking it should be possible to "open" and "close" the sphere
on the outside and if it is open I want to interact with the inside Sphere.

My approach was to deactivate the collider on opening the ouside sphere, but then of course I can´t close it again.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're on the right track with deactivating the collider. Can you draw a diagram of what it would look like with the outer sphere open? You can probably create a second collider for that state and toggle the open/close colliders as needed.

Comment: That´s accually a good idea.
Is there any possibility to create a collider that just reacts on right mouse clicks?

Comment: You can give it a physics layer and apply a layer mask to your raycasts. Info about layers: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html

Comment: Alright. I found another work around without the layers, but thank you anyway. This might come in handy in the future.

Just to give my solution: I deactivate the collider on MouseDown event and activate it again on MouseUp. Since MouseUp is not related to the collider everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: That's a clever solution! It's a little wonky but definitely viable.